# Not able to get "Add here" option in main placeholder after assigning Page Design to a page

Tags: sxa

I have attached a page design to a particular page which consists of Header and Footer as separate partial designs.

After doing this, I am not able to add any components onto main placeholder.

In fact, I am not getting "Add here" option in the page.

Kindly let me know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Do you have a placeholder setting item in Sitecore with the same value as your placeholder key?

Comment: No @ChrisAuer, I didn't create any placeholder setting as of now.

Comment: That’s your issue. You need a placeholder setting or nothing will show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was struggling with the same issue the other day.

Solution is pretty simple.

I assume that you have assigned Header partial design to `header` placeholder and Footer partial design to `footer` placeholder in respective partial designs.

In Page design therefore `header` and `footer` placeholders are not available anymore.

I believe that in Page design you have assigned Page Content component or something similar to `main` placeholder.

When these three things are like this, when you are in Experience Editor you won't see "Add here" anymore as all placeholders are "taken".

To enable something in `main` placeholder, put there Row splitter component in Page design and move everything that you had in `main` placeholder to first row.
Then you will be able to add new content in second row of that splitter.

More information here:

- https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/building_the_layout/structure/change_the_layout_of_a_page

Answer (score 0):

In the Content Editor, you can set placeholder restrictions for your layout placeholders. These restrictions are applied on all pages in the site. For example, if you add restrictions for a footer, these apply for all footers on every page of the site. In this way, you can control the content that content owners can place in layout placeholders.

To add a placeholder setting for a site:

1. Navigate to the Presentation folder of your site, right-click Placeholder Settings, click Insert, and then click Placeholder.

[image]

2. Enter a name and click
3. In the Data section, in the Allowed Controls field, click Edit.

[image]

4. In the Select Items dialog box, navigate to Layout/Rendering/Feature/Experience Accelerator and select the renderings that you want to enable, and then click OK. For example, if you want a very simple footer, enable only the Rich Text (Reusable), Twitter, and Link renderings for the footer.

[image]

5. Save the placeholder setting.
   Now in the Experience Editor, when you click Add here, for example, in the footer, you can only select the renderings that you just added. Other renderings can still appear in the Toolbox but the content owner is not able to drag them to the placeholder.

[image]

[image]

More details can be found here: 
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/setting_up_and_configuring/configuring/set_placeholder_restrictions

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have a rendering in the placeholder in a partial.  So if your partial has a component in the main placeholder, the user will be unable to add that component to the placeholder in the content pages.